# Why is Local Laravel api being debugged through its local consumer

Tags: laravel, api, connection, local

I'm trying to get a local api and local website(consumer of api) to work together for last two days but no joy.
Local Api: apishop.test
Local Consumer: frontendflex.test
When i connect to a live api (like fakestoreapi.com) it works fine from Local Consumer website. Both my own local api and the fakestoreapi produce valid json on screen

I have tried various ways to communicate with the local api that dont work.

`$res=json_decode(file_get_contents('http://apishop.test/products/' . $request->product)`
error..
file_get_contents(https://apishop.test/products/2): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

`$res = Http::acceptJson()->get('http://apishop.test/products/' . $request->product);`

ErrorException
Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\Client\Response::$title (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\frontendflex\resources\views\shop\product.blade.php). This makes sense beacause if I dd($res) it is 500 internal server error like file_get_contents()

So to curl...

```
       curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://apishop.test/products/2');
       curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']??null);
       curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

       //$res= json_decode(curl_exec($handle), true); //Attempt to read property "title" on null
        //$res= curl_exec($handle); //Attempt to read property "title" on string

       curl_close($handle);
```

But when I dd($res) it spews out crazy error data at which the top is....

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'frontendflex.products' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`id` = 2 limit 1)
http://apishop.test/products/2

There is NO products table here, it is in api website. I'm running frontendflex.test here. So getting more curious, I deliberately caused an error in api website code and it picked it up on the consumer website frontendflex.test. What's going on here ?? Both websites are totally separated but under xampp. Head-banging for two days now. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well in desperation i created a brand new clean laravel project, just one controller and one route to access the api and it worked. So, I need to drill down as to what is happening with the other site. Mis-config somewhere.

Edit:
I discovered that for some reason if i access the consumer website (frontendflex.test) by php artisan:serve (http://127.0.0.1:8000/doda)it accesses the api site apishop.test no problem. Weird, but not wonderful!! Anybody out there that can shine a light on this?

Edit: Discovered a workaround.
Change port for consumer site to http://frontendflex.test:8080/doda

```
    NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/frontendflex/public"
    ServerName frontendflex.test
</VirtualHost>
```

Changed to this in apache vhosts file
This works but i would like to know why other way does not work.
Hope this helps someone somewhere someday :)